# Deleting task from planner

Tags: microsoft-graph-plannertasks

I'm having trouble trying to delete the task through the graph API with the following code

```
for index, row in tasks_df[:1].iterrows():
    task_id_to_delete = row['TASK_ID']
    print(task_id_to_delete)
    
    delete_task_url = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/planner/tasks/{task_id_to_delete}'
    headers = {
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}',
        'If-Match': '*' 
    }

    delete_task_response = requests.delete(delete_task_url, headers=headers)

    if delete_task_response.status_code == 204:
        print(f'Tarefa {task_id_to_delete} excluída com sucesso.')
    else:
        print(f'Erro ao excluir a tarefa {task_id_to_delete}: {delete_task_response.status_code} - {delete_task_response.text}')
```

It presents the following error: 500 -

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "",
        "message": "The given key was not present in the dictionary.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2024-03-01T14:36:11",
            "request-id": "111111111111111111",
            "client-request-id": "11111111111111111"
        }
    }
}
```